# fast forward merge strangeness

Tags: git, merge

Is it possible that a fast forward merge in Git could have changed the commit hash? I had a branch that merged into a remote that got another commit on it. The next merge into that branch did not produce a merge commit but seems to have recreated the original merge with a new hash. Is that the expected behavior?

Comment: This seems rather unusual. Can you show your git log before and after the merge ?

Comment: Sounds like it wasn't actually a fast forward.

Comment: I did not actually perform the merge myself, but saw the cygwin console of my coworker who did. The results looked like a fast forward merge where it displayed the affected files and the ----+++ differences. In our bitbucket though all I was able to pull up later were two consecutive "commits" to the two branches that looked identical but had different commit hashes. We reverted the second commit and did a merge with the --no-ff addition and got a merge commit that was again identical. It however was tagged as a merge.